# TinyMCE: Customize style-names in styleselect-menu

Tags: javascript, tinymce, richtextediting

Let's say I have a CSS class named *foo* but would like it to be shown as *foo (1)* in the TinyMCE styleselect-menu (one of the [default buttons available in the advanced theme](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Control_reference)).

I tried using the [class_filter](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/class_filter) option to do this, but that doesn't seem to work.

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try initializing using the [theme_advanced_styles](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/theme_advanced_styles) option.

Comment: Man, you absolutely made my day! I just couldn't find this option! Thanks a lot!